# Как поменять цвет точек маршрута в яндекс картах

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Мне нужно поменять цвет WayPoint на яндекс карте, сейчас они по дефолту синии и красные, нужны оранжевые.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(function () {
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.028888,82.926484],
            zoom: 9,
            // Добавим панель маршрутизации.
            controls: ['routePanelControl']
        });

        var control = myMap.controls.get('routePanelControl');

        // Зададим состояние панели для построения машрутов.
        control.routePanel.state.set({
            // Тип маршрутизации.
            type: 'masstransit',
            // Выключим возможность задавать пункт отправления в поле ввода.
            fromEnabled: true,
            // Адрес или координаты пункта отправления.

            // Включим возможность задавать пункт назначения в поле ввода.
            toEnabled: false,
            // Адрес или координаты пункта назначения.
            to: 'Новосибирская область, р.п. Коченево, ул. Южная, 23',

        });



        // Зададим опции панели для построения машрутов.
        control.routePanel.options.set({
            // Запрещаем показ кнопки, позволяющей менять местами начальную и конечную точки маршрута.
             allowSwitch: false,
            // Включим определение адреса по координатам клика.
            // Адрес будет автоматически подставляться в поле ввода на панели, а также в подпись метки маршрута.
            reverseGeocoding: true,
            // Зададим виды маршрутизации, которые будут доступны пользователям для выбора.
            types: { masstransit: true, pedestrian: true, taxi: true }
        });

        // Создаем кнопку, с помощью которой пользователи смогут менять местами начальную и конечную точки маршрута.
        var switchPointsButton = new ymaps.control.Button({
            data: {content: "Поменять местами", title: "Поменять точки местами"},
            options: {selectOnClick: false, maxWidth: 160}
        });
        // Объявляем обработчик для кнопки.
        switchPointsButton.events.add('click', function () {
            // Меняет местами начальную и конечную точки маршрута.
            control.routePanel.switchPoints();
        });


        myMap.controls.add(switchPointsButton);
    });

</script>
```

There is such a code, I can't figure out how to change their color in it.

Answer (score 0):

Параметры путевых точек задаются через опции мультимаршрута ([пример от Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_view_options/)). Получить маршрут, построенный через панель маршрутизации (как в вашем случае), можно методом `control.routePanel.getRouteAsync();` Подробнее про работу с методом написано в [документации](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/router/routePanel.html#routePanel__get-route-info).

Ниже я добавил нужные параметры к вашему примеру:

```js
ymaps.ready(function() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.028888, 82.926484],
    zoom: 9,
    // Добавим панель маршрутизации.
    controls: ['routePanelControl']
  });

  var control = myMap.controls.get('routePanelControl');

  // Зададим состояние панели для построения машрутов.
  control.routePanel.state.set({
    // Тип маршрутизации.
    type: 'masstransit',
    // Выключим возможность задавать пункт отправления в поле ввода.
    fromEnabled: true,
    // Адрес или координаты пункта отправления.

    // Включим возможность задавать пункт назначения в поле ввода.
    toEnabled: false,
    // Адрес или координаты пункта назначения.
    to: 'Новосибирская область, р.п. Коченево, ул. Южная, 23',

  });

  // Зададим опции панели для построения машрутов.
  control.routePanel.options.set({
    // Запрещаем показ кнопки, позволяющей менять местами начальную и конечную точки маршрута.
    allowSwitch: false,
    // Включим определение адреса по координатам клика.
    // Адрес будет автоматически подставляться в поле ввода на панели, а также в подпись метки маршрута.
    reverseGeocoding: true,
    // Зададим виды маршрутизации, которые будут доступны пользователям для выбора.
    types: {
      masstransit: true,
      pedestrian: true,
      taxi: true
    }
  });

  // Создаем кнопку, с помощью которой пользователи смогут менять местами начальную и конечную точки маршрута.
  var switchPointsButton = new ymaps.control.Button({
    data: {
      content: "Поменять местами",
      title: "Поменять точки местами"
    },
    options: {
      selectOnClick: false,
      maxWidth: 160
    }
  });
  // Объявляем обработчик для кнопки.
  switchPointsButton.events.add('click', function() {
    // Меняет местами начальную и конечную точки маршрута.
    control.routePanel.switchPoints();
  });
  
  myMap.controls.add(switchPointsButton);

  // Получение объекта, описывающего построенные маршруты.
  var multiRoutePromise = control.routePanel.getRouteAsync();
  multiRoutePromise.then(function(multiRoute) {
    multiRoute.options.set({
      // Цвет метки начальной точки.
      wayPointStartIconFillColor: "orange",
      // Цвет метки конечной точки.
      wayPointFinishIconFillColor: "orange",
      // Внешний вид линий (для всех маршрутов).
      routeStrokeColor: "orange"
    });
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=a2d2f39e-5c7c-4ba9-ba21-f687c5c54471">
</script>
<style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
</style>
```